# How can I resolve conflicting Fabric strings resources in a Unity3d-exported gradle project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-fabric

The fabric Unity preprocess step generates a `strings.xml` with the app uuid. If I export the gradle project to open with Android Studio, fabric generates a conflicting `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml`, even if I set `ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false` to try and suppress it.

It appears the problem is that the gradle process is specifically looking for `com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml`, creating one if it doesn't exist. My workaround is to modify the fabric Unity preprocess step to write to this filename rather than `strings.xml`.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Were you able to find a workaround to this? Does build fail in AS with this change?

Comment: I added my workaround to the post.